# 1 SSD or 2 SSDs? for VMWare virtual environments

Tags: ssd, vmware-workstation

I would like to know if it’s better if I buy 1 SSD for my OS like 120GB and 1 512GB SSD for my VMWare workstation virtual environment.

Or do you think that i can also buy 1 SSD and run the OS and 2 virtual environments with no problems? They are really fast...

Comment: How much performance do you really need in terms of hard drive usage? I run the OS and 3 VMs on a HDD (not SSD) and they work fine. You must give more details/usage scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use a Crucial 128GB SSD for my OS, applications, and desktop work/scratch area. All of my VM's, however, are installed on a Crucial 256GB SSD. This is because it is possible for several VM to flood the SATA bus. Just ask yourself how much data will you be writing per second. Everything is crazy fast if you keep 'em separate.